# Скрывать объекты которые за камерой

Tags: unity3d

В начале игры на сцене появляется много объектов, которые не должны быть видны, если игрок их не видит.
Как сделать такое?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

Comment: думаю это то что вам нужно

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, объекты, которые **не попадают ни в одну камеру** итак не отображаются/не рендаряться. А почему они видны в редакторе в окне `Scene` - потому что попадают в камеру данного окна.

Comment: не должны быть видны или должны быть выключенны скрипты на них?

Comment: @Andrey речь в вопросе про Frustum culling, а не occlusion.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать эти методы.

- OnBecameInvisible вызывается, когда средство рендеринга больше не видно ни с одной камеры.
- OnBecameVisible вызывается, когда средство визуализации стало видимым для любой камеры.